# Change starting point for NumPy's FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am having trouble with NumPy's FFT. I dont want the curve to shoot up at the end like what is shown in the image. It is almost like it is pinned at the average price for the stock price.

```
close_fft = np.fft.fft(np.asarray(data_FT['Adj Close'].tolist()))
fft_df = pd.DataFrame({'fft':close_fft})
fft_df['absolute'] = fft_df['fft'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x))
fft_df['angle'] = fft_df['fft'].apply(lambda x: np.angle(x))

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7), dpi=100)
fft_list = np.asarray(fft_df['fft'].tolist())
for num_ in [3, 6, 9, 100]:
    fft_list_m10= np.copy(fft_list); fft_list_m10[num_:-num_]=0
    plt.plot(np.fft.ifft(fft_list_m10), label='Fourier transform with {} components'.format(num_))
plt.plot(data_FT['GS'],  label='Real')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.title('Figure 3: Goldman Sachs (close) stock prices & Fourier transforms')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

As you can see the curves jump right up to where they started no matter the original price. The original tutorial I am following is here:
https://pythonawesome.com/using-the-latest-advancements-in-ai-to-predict-stock-market-movements/

Comment: The FFT is based on the assumption that the signal is periodic, so what you see is to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT's basis vectors are all circular, thus a reduced number of them can not easily represent a sharp discontinuity between the end of the array and the beginning.  You can try to get rid of some of the jumps by mirroring the data at each end, and/or by de-trending the data before the FFT to reduce some of the discontinuity.

Added:

The DCT method is to simply duplicate the data with its mirror image (e.g. in reverse order) and use a double length FFT.  Throw away the extra samples after your processing.

The de-trend method can be done by using the linear trend, or maybe with a linear regression fit of a very low order polynomial.  Subtract the fitted trend, then FFT and do your processing. Then after processing add the fitted trend line back if needed.

Comment: Good idea! I will take my dataset and get a previous close difference, hopefully that will give me a less jumpy plot. I will give it a go then update later tonight.

Comment: Truncate the first couple of days and the last couple of days.